# Drupal 9 Compilation Install Error

Tags: drupal-9

I’m trying get CiviCRM working on a Drupal 9.1.9 test site. I know CiviCRM but not Drupal…
I followed this: https://docs.civicrm.org/installation/en/latest/drupal8/

These are the commands I ran to install it:

php composer.phar create-project drupal/recommended-project

php composer.phar require pear/validate_finance_creditcard:dev-master

php composer.phar config extra.enable-patching true

php composer.phar require civicrm/civicrm-asset-plugin:'~1.1'

php composer.phar require civicrm/civicrm-{core,packages,drupal-8}:'~5.37.2'

The last command does a lot of installing and then gives me:

[Exception]
Cannot prompt for compilation preferences. Please update COMPOSER_COMPILE, extra.compile-mode, or extra.compile-whitelist.

compile [--all] [-N|--dry-run] [--soft-options [SOFT-OPTIONS]] [--] []...

Subcommand @composer compile  returned with error code 1

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.

[RuntimeException]
Subcommand @composer compile  returned with error code 1

Composer version 2.0.14 PHP 7.4.14

Can someone please assist…thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this line to the top level composer.json and then run `composer compile`:

`"compile-whitelist": ["civicrm/civicrm-core", "civicrm/composer-compile-lib"]`

Then it won't try to prompt you next time for upgrades either.

Comment: Being a dummy, I didn't know where to put the line of code, but the 3rd try worked...thanks!!! I put it near the end, before:
        "enable-patching": "true"